# Parse.com adding a row to a class programmatically

Tags: ios, parse-platform, row, addition

I have a class called "Groups". I want a user to be able to create a group in the app. Is there an "addRow" feature with parse so that it creates a new row in the Parse class when a method is called in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in doc:

```
PFObject *newGroup = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Groups"];
newGroup[@"propertyName"] = propertyValue;
[newGroup saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
{
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error saving %@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"Successfully added a group");
}];
```

[More details here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS)